Magnitude of current produced by induced emf
By Faraday's law, we can find the magnitude of the induced emf in a coil due to another neighboring coil which is $v = M \ \mathrm{d}i/\mathrm{d}t$. What is the magnitude of the current produced by this emf if the coil (circuit) has no resistance and is purely inductive? Now does this current again produce its own field and affect the neighboring coil that produced this current in the first place?

Please include a schematic diagram to make it clear what situation you are asking about.

What you are describing is two coupled ideal inductors. Let their individual inductances be $L_1$ and $L_2$ and their mutual inductance $M$.
This pair of differential equations defines the relationships between the voltages and currents in each inductor.
$$V_1 = -L_1I_1'+MI_2'$$
$$V_2 = MI_1'-L_2I_2'.$$

What is the magnitude of the current produced by this emf if the coil (circuit) has no resistance and is purely inductive?

I understand this question to be: what is current in the 2nd coil? Of course, there will be no current in the second coil if the terminals of the coil are left open. So I understand your question to mean: what is the current in the 2nd coil if the terminals of the 2nd coil are shorted together?
In that case, the voltage across the terminals will be $0$, so $V_2=0$.
So,
$$MI_1'=L_2I_2'$$
or,
$$I_2' = \frac{M}{L_2}I_1'$$
$$I_2 = \frac{M}{L_2}\int I_1' \, \mathrm{d}t.$$

Now, does this current again produce its own field and affect the neighboring coil that produced this current in the first place?

Yes, a changing current in coil 2 induces an emf in coil 1 in the amount of $MI_2'$.
However, before jumping to the conclusion that we must consider an infinite number of effects, and the effects of those effects and so on, remember this. In your (resistance-free) circuit,
$$I_2' = \frac{M}{L_2}I_1'.$$
If you know $I_1'$, you can find $I_2'$, and vice-versa. So you should ask whether or not you know $I_1'$. You will know $I_1'$ if the current through coil 1 is constrained by an ideal current source. If that is the case, then you know $I_1'$, can calculate $I_2'$ and can calculate the voltage across coil 1, using
$$V_1 = -L_1I_1'+MI_2'.$$
However, if the voltage across coil 1 is controlled by an ideal voltage source, the emf induced in coil 1 cannot affect the terminal voltage. Instead, the emf induced by the current in coil 2 will have an effect on the current in coil 1. This is the essence of transformer action.
In this case, we know the applied voltage across coil 1, and the ratio between $I_1'$ and $I_2'$. We can combine these two equations:
$$V_1 = -L_1I_1'+MI_2'\quad \text{and} \quad I_2' = \frac{M}{L_2}I_1'$$
to get
$$V_1 = -L_1'I_1'+M\frac{M}{L_2}I_1'$$
or
$$I_1'=\frac{V_1}{-L_1+\dfrac{M^2}{L_2}},$$
which allows us to calculate $I_1'$.
To possibly give you an intuition about what's happening in transformer action, I offer the following narrative. A voltage across the primary of a transformer leads to a changing current through the primary of the transformer. This leads to a changing magnetic flux. This leads to a current in the secondary (assuming such a current is possible). But, the flux cannot change without there being a change in the primary voltage, which is set by the ideal voltage source. So, a current must arise in the primary that cancels the flux change that would have been induced by the secondary current. In other words, the secondary current causes a reflected current in the primary.


What is the magnitude of the current produced by this emf if the coil (circuit) has no resistance and is purely inductive?

If the coil is connected into a closed conductive path,  we can apply Kirchhoff's second circuital law:
Sum of emfs acting in a closed path equals sum of terms $R_kI_k$, one for each element in the path, where $R_k$ is resistance of the element $k$ and $I_k$ is current flowing through it.
$$
\sum_m \mathscr{E}_m = \sum_k R_kI_k.
$$
If the coil has zero ohmic resistance, and free ends of the coil are connected with a wire with zero ohmic resistance (ends are shorted out), the right-hand side in this equation is zero. We have two emfs in the circuit with coil 1: the mutual emf, due to  current $I_2$ in the second coil changing in time, and the self-induced emf, due to current $I_1$ in the first coil changing in time. Mathematically, this can be written as the following differential equation:
$$
-M_{12} \frac{dI_2}{dt} - L_1\frac{dI_1}{dt} = 0.
$$
Here, both $M_{12}$ and $L_1$ are assumed constant (motion of the coil is negligible if any). Also, $L_1$ is always positive, and we use the convention where $M_{12}$ for two identical coils with almost the same position in space (one being close to the other) is positive; $M_{12}$ can be negative if the other coil has different enough orientation in space.
We can integrate this equation in time to get
$$
-M_{12}I_2 - L_1I_1 = C,
$$
where $C$ is some constant (independent of time).  Now, imagine there is a time $t_0$ when the current $I_1$ is zero, and let's denote $I_2(t_0) = I_{2,0}$. We can then express the constant as $ C= -M_{12}I_{2,0}$, and express the current in the first coil $I_1$ as a function of the other current $I_2$ in the coil 2:
$$
I_1 = \frac{M_{12}}{L_1}\bigg(I_{2,0} - I_2\bigg).
$$
If the coils are similar and close to each other, so $M_{12}$ is positive, this implies that when current in the coil 2 increases, the current in the coil 1 decreases, and vice versa. It also implies that if one current does not change in time, the other also does not change in time, and we have two constant currents.

Now does this current again produce its own field and affect the neighboring coil that produced this current in the first place?

Yes, the coil 2 is affected by mutual induction in the same way, that is, there is mutual EMF in the coil 2 due to current $I_1$ changing in time.
If ends of the coil 2 are short-circuited as well, so we have two similar circuits without any resistance and without any other source of EMF, the same analysis applies to the coil 2 and it implies the differential equation
$$
-M_{21} \frac{dI_1}{dt} - L_2\frac{dI_2}{dt} = 0.
$$
It can be shown in EM theory that $M_{12} = M_{21}$, so we can use just one symbol $M$ and write down both equations this way:
$$
- L_1\frac{dI_1}{dt} -M \frac{dI_2}{dt}  = 0.
$$
$$
-M \frac{dI_1}{dt} - L_2\frac{dI_2}{dt} = 0.
$$
These equations can be solved and it can be shown that both currents are constant in time. Thus in two perfectly conducting, mutually coupled circuits, currents in them are constant, there is no change in currents (in particular, there is no oscillation of currents which one might expect). It takes some other factor, such as resistance in one of the circuits or a source of additional EMF in one of the circuits, to change currents in both circuits.
